# Demoing XSS Attack in Apache

Tags: php, apache, security, xss

So I want to create a basic form that is vulnurable to XSS for demo purposes. The code I've written looks like this

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>
            Enter your name
        </h1>
        <form action="xssDemo.php" method="post">
            <label> What is your name? </label>
            <input type="text" name="yourName" size="30">
            <input type="submit" name='Btn' value="Submit">
        </form>
        <?php
            if(isset($_POST["Btn"])) {
                echo "Hello " . $_POST["yourName"];
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

The idea is for it to allow me to demo reflected XSS attacks by entering `<script>alert("XSS")</script>` However, Apache apparently has some built in security against XSS attacks as it filters my attack. How do I shut that off in Apache? Using XAMPP and Chrome if that matters.

Edit: Output is just "Hello "

Comment: and what is the output?

Comment: Just hello (added to question)

Comment: When you view source what is there next to hello?

Comment: Apache does not have built-in xss protection, but chrome does.  Try your POC in FF.

Answer (score 0):

So I ran it in Internet Explorer and it works.